# didChangeAuthorizationStatus is run when authorization is not changed

Tags: ios, cllocationmanager

I have created a button. When the button is clicked I want to get my location. I have to ask user for permission before I will use location manager. Please look at my code:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didChangeAuthorizationStatus:(CLAuthorizationStatus)status {
    if (status == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedAlways || status == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedWhenInUse) {
        [self startGettingLocation];
    }
}

- (IBAction)locationButtonAction:(id)sender {
    if (status == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedAlways || status == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedWhenInUse) {
        [self startGettingLocation];
    } else if (status == kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined) {
        [self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
    }
}
```

The problem is that the method `locationManager:didChangeAuthorizationStatus` is run after view did load too! Method `startGettingLocation` is started when the user doesn't click button. How to change this code to run `startGettingLocation` only when user clicks on button.

Answer (score 3):

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    self.initialAuthorizationStatus = [CLLocationManager authorizationStatus];

    self.locationManager = [CLLocationManager new];
    self.locationManager.delegate = self;
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didChangeAuthorizationStatus:(CLAuthorizationStatus)status {
    // If status really did change.
    if (self.initialAuthorizationStatus != status) {
        if (status == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedAlways || status == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedWhenInUse) {
            [self startGettingLocation];
        }
    }
}


- (IBAction)locationButtonAction:(id)sender {
    if (status == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedAlways || status == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedWhenInUse) {
        [self startGettingLocation];
    } else if (status == kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined) {
        [self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
    }
}
```